# Bash: loop through lists (array of arrays) and access sublist value

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In BASH, consider a *(pseudo)structured* list of arrays like so:

```bash
## all my arrays definitions:
myArray1=("userList1" "emailList1" "valueList1")
myArray2=("userList2" "emailList2" "valueList2")
...
myArrayN=("userListN" "emailListN" "valueListN")

## a list of the arrays I need to loop through:
active_lists=("myArray1" "myArray2" [... "myArrayN"])
```

I want to loop through each of the arrays I've configured in my `active_lists` *collection*.

This is often mentioned in tutorials and one would assume the following would do the trick:

```bash
for indexd in "${active_lists[@]}"; do
   username=${!indexd}[0]
   email=${!indexd}[1]
   echo "Email: ${email}, username: ${username}"
done
```

Putting all this in a Bash script (with strict mode enabled) should be most straightforward:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

declare -a myArray1=("userList1" "emailList1" "valueList1")
declare -a myArray2=("userList2" "emailList2" "valueList2")

declare -a active_lists=("myArray1" "myArray2")

for indexd in "${active_lists[@]}"; do
   username=${!indexd}[2]
   email=${!indexd}[1]
   echo "Email: ${email}, username: ${username}"

   sublist=(${!indexd})
   echo "List Value: ${sublist[1]}"
done
```

However running the above script results in literal printing of the elements names, or `unbound variable` warning when attempting to access an index in the sublist:

```bash
Email: userList1[1], username: userList1[2]
Email: userList2[1], username: userList2[2]
```

or

```bash
line 16: sublist[1]: unbound variable
```

This should be simple AF and I am obviously missing something fundamental but I cannot figure out what that is, and I'm going mad! Please help.

Comment: Bard and Bing suggested this approach, and I'm pretty sure I've seen something similar in tutorials. Are you saying this is not possible in bash at all?

Comment: This is all but an academic exercise, purely for my understanding.
I wanted to loop through these arrays and assign various indices to local variable for readability (i.e. `for indexd in "${active_lists[@]}"; do` ... `username=${indexd[0]}`).

Answer (score 4):

While there may be a way to use indirect references with arrays (it's going to be a bit convoluted) I find `nameref`s are much simpler to use ...

With `bash 4.3+` you can use a `nameref` to cycle through the different arrays.

One `bash` approach:

```
myArray1=("userList1" "emailList1" "valueList1")
myArray2=("userList2" "emailList2" "valueList2")
myArrayN=("userListN" "emailListN" "valueListN")

active_lists=("myArray1" "myArray2" "myArrayN")

for arr_name in "${active_lists[@]}"
do
    printf "\n####### ${arr_name}\n\n"

    declare -n _arr="${arr_name}"                      # nameref

    for i in "${!_arr[@]}"                             # loop through indices of nameref'd array "_arr[]" (ie, indices of the current "arr_name" array]
    do
        echo "${arr_name}[$i] = ${_arr[i]}"
    done
done
```

**NOTES:**

- `${arr_name}[$i]` is not an array reference but rather 4 strings appended together (`${arr_name}` + `[` + `$i` + `]`) for display purposes
- `${_arr[i]}` *is* an array reference and due to the `nameref` will display the `ith` element of the current `arr_name` array

This generates:

```
####### myArray1

myArray1[0] = userList1
myArray1[1] = emailList1
myArray1[2] = valueList1

####### myArray2

myArray2[0] = userList2
myArray2[1] = emailList2
myArray2[2] = valueList2

####### myArrayN

myArrayN[0] = userListN
myArrayN[1] = emailListN
myArrayN[2] = valueListN
```

Comment: Many thanks, mate! I appreciate you helping me understand this. 
I had tried all sorts of wrong options, quite blindly I'll admit, cause I don't really understand referencing in BASH. Some of my failed attempts included:

`for arr_name in "${active_lists[@]}"; do `
`config_array="${arr_name}[@]"`
`config_array="${arr_name[@]}"`
`config_array="${($arr_name)[@]}"`
`done`

You've clarified all this for me now. Much obliged, sir!

Answer (score 2):

[MarkP-Fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso), thank you very much for [your reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78156732/1211629)! It is indeed the `nameref` that I couldn't get my head around (it's still a bit fuzzy tbh). This is all but an academic exercise, really.

To reiterate, all my initial script was missing was:

```bash
declare -n sublist="${indexd}"
```

Effectively I needed to `declare` a *local copy* of each of my arrays when looping through the array placeholder (i.e. `active_lists`). By doing  `declare -n sublist="${indexd}"` I can read any indices in the array and assign them to local variables.

---

This is my working script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

declare -a myArray1=("userList1" "emailList1" "valueList1")
declare -a myArray2=("userList2" "emailList2" "valueList2")

declare -a active_lists=("myArray1" "myArray2")

for indexd in "${active_lists[@]}"; do
   declare -n sublist="${indexd}"

   username=${sublist[0]}
   email=${sublist[1]}

   echo "List ${indexd}: Email: ${email}, username: ${username} (${sublist[2]})"
done
```

Comment: technically you're not declaring a *local copy* of each array but rather dynamically (re)declaring (on each pass through the loop) a type of symlink from `sublist` to the desired array; if you make a change to `sublist` you'll find the change is actually made to the underlying/referenced array (ie, that wouldn't happen with a *copy* of the array)

Comment: inside the loop add `_arr+=('added in loop')`; after the loop run `typeset -p myArray1 myArray2 myArrayN` and you'll see that all 3 arrays now have an extra entry of `[3]="added in loop"`; net result: changes made to the nameref (`sublist` in your case) flow through to the underlying array

Comment: But if I did something like `sublist="${indexd}"` instead of `declare -n sublist="${indexd}"` that would obviously wouldn't work. However, coming from other languages, I should be able to access the the arrays defined outside of the `for loop`, as you'd expect it to be in the same context.
Bash is strange....